# Can Apache Cordova compile to legacy Windows desktop apps (non-metro)?

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-7, windows-xp, cordova-3

I need to develop an app that retrieves and saves data interacting with users, with a high focus on multi-platform support and rapid development.
The app does not require heavy graphics or processing etc.

I'm considering the use of Apache Cordova.

- Can it compile and run as a native desktop app on Windows (not as WinRT metro app)?
- How about Windows 7 and XP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a windows 7 cordova

https://github.com/otcshare/cordova-win7

More info:
http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/07/12/Windows-7-version-of-PhoneGapCordova

New link https://github.com/fabriceds/cordova-win7

And I have forked it so it will never be deleted https://github.com/jcesarmobile/cordova-win7

Comment: How about having Cordova as native app in Win 8?

Comment: if you create it with cordova-win7 it should work on Win 8 too as desktop app. The regular cordova create universal apps for WP8 and Win 8, but they are "store apps", not desktop apps.

Comment: Is there any way to have Apache Cordova run on XP as a native app as well?

Comment: take a look into cordova node-webkit https://github.com/xverges/cordova-nodewebkit http://justbuildsomething.com/making-desktop-javascript-apps-with-nodewebkit/

Comment: FYI: cordova-win7 is no longer available on github, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks, added a new link