# Build Cordova App for Windows 7

Tags: cordova, windows-7

Is it possible to build Windows 7 applications with Cordova/Phonegap?

The documentation only mentions Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8. Searching for Windows 7 compability gave me nothing.

Setting the values of target-platform to "7.0" in config.xml and default.xml doesn't work either and will just tell me that I can't build Windows 7 apps in my OS or Enviroment, which is false, given that I can just do one natively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Apache Cordova compile to legacy Windows desktop apps (non-metro)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28666309/can-apache-cordova-compile-to-legacy-windows-desktop-apps-non-metro)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Improved version

https://github.com/eposjk/cordova-windows7

Old message:
There is a windows 7 port of cordova created by intel

https://github.com/otcshare/cordova-win7

More info: http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/07/12/Windows-7-version-of-PhoneGapCordova

EDIT: here is another link to cordova windows 7
https://github.com/fabriceds/cordova-win7

And I have forked it so it will never be deleted
https://github.com/jcesarmobile/cordova-win7

Comment: note: 'cordova-win7 appears to be no longer available.

Comment: updated the link, @mattlohkamp, can you please remove the downvote?

Comment: thanks! I looked around a lot to try to find an alt link - must've missed this one. and thanks for the fork as insurance, as well.

Comment: There is an improved version at https://github.com/eposjk/cordova-windows7 which contains many bugfixes and is updated to cordova 2.9.1 (The original version is based on cordova 2.1.0).